# How do I prevent a fixed position <ul> from overlaying links which is preventing them from being clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've coded out some buttons that display on the bottom right of our website on mobile and placed them with an `<ul>` element. To animate the buttons, I have translated each of the `<li>` elements, as soon as the code is executed, on the Y-axis so that they all line up together and only the last element can be seen. However, I've noticed that even though it's translated, the height of the `<ul>` remains the same size as it was before the jQuery was executed and it's preventing some links on the website from being clicked. I know that's probably confusing, so I created an easy example below to showcase the issue. **If you notice, the link cannot be clicked above the buttons, even when they are out of the way.**

```js
$(() => {

    let $menuToggleButton = $('.menu-toggle-button');
    let $menuItems = $('.menu-item-button').closest('.menu-item');
    let menuItemCount =  $menuItems.length;

    hideButtons($menuItems, menuItemCount, $menuToggleButton);
    $('.menu-items').show();

    $menuToggleButton.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let active = $(this).hasClass('active');
        if(active) {
            hideButtons($menuItems, menuItemCount, $(this));
        } else {
            showButtons($menuItems, $(this));
        }
    });

    function hideButtons($menuItems, menuItemCount, $menuToggleButton) {
        let x = 0;
        for (let i = menuItemCount; i > 0; i--) {
            let $menuItem = $menuItems.eq(x);
            let offsetPercentage = `${i * 100}%`;
            $menuItem.css('transform', `translateY(${offsetPercentage})`);
            x++;
        }
        $menuToggleButton.removeClass('active');
    }

    function showButtons($menuItems, $menuToggleButton) {
        $menuToggleButton.addClass('active');
        $menuItems.each(function() {
            $(this).css('transform', 'translateY(0%)');
        });
    }

});
```

```css
.sliding-pill-menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.menu-items {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 5px 0;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-item-button,
.menu-toggle-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #EC2127;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: inherit;
  min-width: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-item-button:hover, .menu-item-button:active, .menu-item-button:link, .menu-item-button:visited,
.menu-toggle-button:hover,
.menu-toggle-button:active,
.menu-toggle-button:link,
.menu-toggle-button:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-item-icon,
.menu-toggle-icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.underlay-btn {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="underlay-btn" href="#">Click Me Instead</a>
<div class="sliding-pill-menu">
  <ul class="menu-items">
    <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-button" href="tel:5555555555"><i class="menu-item-icon fa fa-mobile"></i>Call Now</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-button" href="sms:5555555555"><i class="menu-item-icon fa fa-sms"></i>Send Text</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-button" href="/order-by-date"><i class="menu-item-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>Check Availability</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-toggle-button" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus menu-toggle-icon"></i>Get Started</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I prevent the `<ul>` from blocking the links behind it? I've tried z-index, but I don't think it will work in this case since the app buttons need to remain above everything else.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to utilize the `pointer-events` CSS property to disallow pointer events for the containing `.sliding-pill-menu` element, and only allow them for the individual `.menu-items`.

Essentially you just need to add the following:

```
.sliding-pill-menu {  
  pointer-events: none;
}

.menu-item {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

See the full working example below. In addition to the CSS properties above, I just added a click event for the `.underlay-btn` to toggle its background color to visually show the click is working.

```js
$(() => {

    let $menuToggleButton = $('.menu-toggle-button');
    let $menuItems = $('.menu-item-button').closest('.menu-item');
    let menuItemCount =  $menuItems.length;
    let underlayBtn = $('.underlay-btn');

    underlayBtn.on('click', function(e) {
       $(this).toggleClass('click-proof');
    });

    hideButtons($menuItems, menuItemCount, $menuToggleButton);
    $('.menu-items').show();

    $menuToggleButton.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let active = $(this).hasClass('active');
        if(active) {
            hideButtons($menuItems, menuItemCount, $(this));
        } else {
            showButtons($menuItems, $(this));
        }
    });

    function hideButtons($menuItems, menuItemCount, $menuToggleButton) {
        let x = 0;
        for (let i = menuItemCount; i > 0; i--) {
            let $menuItem = $menuItems.eq(x);
            let offsetPercentage = `${i * 100}%`;
            $menuItem.css('transform', `translateY(${offsetPercentage})`);
            x++;
        }
        $menuToggleButton.removeClass('active');
    }

    function showButtons($menuItems, $menuToggleButton) {
        $menuToggleButton.addClass('active');
        $menuItems.each(function() {
            $(this).css('transform', 'translateY(0%)');
        });
    }

});
```

```css
.sliding-pill-menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  z-index: 10000;   
  pointer-events: none;
}

.menu-items {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 5px 0;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.menu-item-button,
.menu-toggle-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #EC2127;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: inherit;
  min-width: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-item-button:hover, .menu-item-button:active, .menu-item-button:link, .menu-item-button:visited,
.menu-toggle-button:hover,
.menu-toggle-button:active,
.menu-toggle-button:link,
.menu-toggle-button:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-item-icon,
.menu-toggle-icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.underlay-btn {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 300px;
}

.click-proof {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="underlay-btn" href="#">Click Me Instead</a>
<div class="sliding-pill-menu">
  <ul class="menu-items">
    <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-button" href="tel:5555555555"><i class="menu-item-icon fa fa-mobile"></i>Call Now</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-button" href="sms:5555555555"><i class="menu-item-icon fa fa-sms"></i>Send Text</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-button" href="/order-by-date"><i class="menu-item-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>Check Availability</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-toggle-button" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus menu-toggle-icon"></i>Get Started</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```